# React router dom not rendering child component but url changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have child routes and when I'm trying to change the routes in AppMain.js its changing the url but the component is not getting rendered, instead the existing component is getting re-rendered. But if I am doing the same history.push inside `Dashboard` or `BatteryTable` the route is working fine.

App.js

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(Auth)} />
  <Route path="/main" component={withRouter(AppMain)} />
</Router>
```

AppMain.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.history.push('/main/dashboard')  
}

render() {
    return(
        <Routes match={match} />
    )
}
```

Routes.js

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/dashboard`} component={withRouter(Dashboard)} />
        <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/batterytable`} component={withRouter(BatteryTable)} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: might be because you are using two router hoc, remove from Routes.js component, use only in App component. Also when you are rendering the component with route path `withRouter` hoc is not needed, remove that aslo.

Comment: @MayankShukla Then how would the child route work?

Comment: it will work, we only need one instance of `Router`, it should wrapper of whole app only. it will track all the route and path change.

Comment: @MayankShukla Could you please post this as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using `Router` component twice, remove it from `Routes.js` file, We only need to use it once, as the wrapper of whole App.

Use this code in `Routes.js` file:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/dashboard`} component={withRouter(Dashboard)} />
    <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/batterytable`} component={withRouter(BatteryTable)} />
</Switch>
```

**Suggestion**:

Since you are rending Auth and AppMain with route path directly, so you don't need to use `withRouter`. These components will directly get all the router props.